# Proving that a multivariable function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

need helping showing that this function is differentiable,

$f:[a,b]\times[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}:[a,b]\times[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous. 
Need to prove that $F:[a,b]\times[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$F(t)=\int_a^t f(x,t) dx$ , $t \in [a,b]$ is differentiable on (a,b).

Now i know what the derivative of t is, and by using the FTC and the fact that i can put the differential inside the integral so that it becomes a partial differential, i got that

$F'(t) = f(t,t) + \int_a^t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)dx.$

But im struggling to prove why its differentiable. I started off by trying to use the FTC and separating the integral into two different partially differentiable functions in terms of t and x, but i didn't really get anywhere. But to show you my efforts so far i called the integral I and partially differentiated it with respect to t and x separately, then tried putting them together but it I couldn't seem to prove what was required.

Comment: I'm lost: if you say that **you know** that $\;F'(t)=...\;$ then you're saying  that you know $\;F'\;$ exists and thus that $\;F\;$ is differentiable...what else is there to prove?!

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a typo above? Is it supposed to be $$\int_a^t f(t,x)dx$$ rather than $$\int_a^tf(x,t)dx$$ perhaps?

Comment: sorry, i have to prove its differentiable then go on to show what its derivative it. Using given results i can calculate its derivative correctly but cannot seem to give a proof why.